# Generate Dates recursively in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have some dates I want to calculate which is currently done over several subqueries. Each subsequent subquery uses the result (a date) of the previous query in its calculation. E.g.

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '20170101'

SELECT @foo1 = (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.DateFunction(DateField) 
                FROM [DateTable]
                WHERE DateField <= @Date
                ORDER BY DateField DESC)

SELECT @foo2 = (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.DateFunction(DateField) 
                FROM [DateTable]
                WHERE DateField <= @foo1
                ORDER BY DateField DESC)

....

SELECT @fooN = (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.DateFunction(DateField) 
                FROM [DateTable]
                WHERE DateField <= @fooNMinus1
                ORDER BY DateField DESC)
```

Is it possible (perhaps using CTE) to make a recursive query to achieve this for a specified number of times?

Comment: Why are you using `TOP 1` without `ORDER BY`?  Also, what does `DateFunction()` do?

Comment: Function Returns the date the business week commences for a given date. TOP 1 and ORDER BY DESC as I need the most recent date. EDIT-  Sorry I thought you wrote 'WITH', I forgot to add the ORDER BY in the post!

Comment: Can you post your code for `dbo.DateFunction()`? There may be another way to approach this that would perform better than recursion.

Comment: Looking at the function, I can get away with simply returning the first day of the week (e.g. DateAdd(d, -((@@DATEFIRST + DatePart(dw, @MidWeekDate) -2) % 7), @MidWeekDate))

Comment: Can you please add the desired result of your query given a set of input dates?

Answer (score 0):

Weeks are almost always 7 days, so you can get the first one and then just add seven days.  If so:

```
WITH dates as (
      SELECT MAX(dbo.DateFunction(DateField)) as dte, 1 as counter
      FROM [DateTable]
      WHERE DateField <= @Date
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 7, dte), counter + 1
      FROM dates
      WHERE counter < @n
     )
SELECT dte
FROM dates;
```

Comment: The Function has other logic hence 'business days', so adding 7 days will not work. For the purpose of this question it simply returns a date based on a given date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use small tally table as below

```
Declare @d1 date = '2017-01-01'
Declare @d2 date = '2017-12-31' 

select top (datediff(day, @d1, @d2)+1) dt = DateAdd(day, Row_Number() over (order by (Select NULL))-1, @d1) 
from master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2
```

Or custom tally tables

```
;with num as 
( select * from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) v(n) )
, n1 as (select n1.* from num n1, num n2, num n3, num n4) --numbers generation
select top (datediff(day, @d1, @d2)+1) dt = DateAdd(day, Row_Number() over (order by (Select NULL))-1, @d1) 
from n1
```

Comment: Just a quick note to say you can combine the last 2 steps of your tally table for a neater query: `with t(t) as (select * from(values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as v(n)) , d(d) as (select top (datediff(day,@d1,@d2) + 1) dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by(select null)) - 1,@d1) from t t1,t t2,t t3,t t4,t t5,t t6)`

Comment: Yep we can do that, I normally do that way... I just want to keep tally number generation separate and dates generation separate for the post so that it is easily readable from the earlier version

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a recursive query. Since top and aggregates are not allowed in the recursive part, you can use the row_number() function instead.

```
Declare @date date = cast(getdate() as date), @n int = 10

declare @DateTable table (DateField date)
insert into @DateTable values ('2017-05-01'),('2017-05-02'),('2017-05-03'),('2017-05-04'),('2017-05-05'),('2017-05-06'),('2017-05-07'),('2017-05-08'),('2017-05-09'),('2017-05-10'),
                        ('2017-05-11'),('2017-05-12'),('2017-05-13'),('2017-05-14'),('2017-05-15'),('2017-05-16'),('2017-05-17'),('2017-05-18'),('2017-05-19'),('2017-05-20')

;with date_rte as (
    select top 1 dbo.DateFunction(DateField) datefield, 0 recursions, cast(1 as bigint) rn
    from @dateTable
    where datefield <= @date
    order by datefield desc
    union all
    select dbo.DateFunction(DateField), recursions+1, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by d.datefield desc)
    from @datetable d
    join date_rte r on d.DateField <= r.datefield
    where recursions < @n and rn = 1
)

select datefield
from date_rte 
where rn=1 and recursions = @n
```